# Как динамически "урезать" QuerySet?

Tags: django-orm

Помогите разобраться, как используя django-orm можно набрасывать дополнительную фильтрацию уже сформированного queryseta.
Например есть вот такой простенький запрос:

```
raw_query = Employees.objects.all().exclude(hiden='True')
```

Теперь из этого запроса я хочу убрать лишние поля. Нужные поля формируются динамически и результат хранятся в списке, например:

```
fields = list()
fields = ['first_name', 'second_name', 'middle_name']
filter_query = raw_query.values(fields)
```

Но это так не работает, работает только если я укажу это статически:

```
filter_query = raw_query.values('first_name', 'second_name', 'middle_name')
```

Как нужно преобразовать list, что бы его можно было его использовать как аргумент метода .values() ?

Может быть есть другой способ решить эту задачку, буду благодарен за подсказку.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно раскрыть список, подставив * перед fields:

```
fields = ['first_name', 'second_name', 'middle_name']
filter_query = raw_query.values(*fields)
```